# Cannot execute .sh file

Tags: permissions, executable

I am having an issue making a file executable. The file is gatewaystart.sh. I have unzipped a downloaded folder containing the specified file, into /opt/ibc using the command

```
sudo unzip ~/Downloads/IBCLinux-3.18.0.zip -d \
/opt/ibc
```

Next, I make the file executable by running

```
cd /opt/ibc
sudo chmod o+x *.sh */*.sh
```

The issue that I am facing is that when I run gatewaystart.sh after executing those commands in the terminal, the file does not execute. I have tried executing bash gatewaystart.sh and sh gatewaystart.sh however I get the error:

```
gatewaystart.sh: 193: [[: not found
gatewaystart.sh: 195: [[: not found
-e Error: no execute permission for scripts in /opt/ibc/scripts
```

Help on this matter would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: take this literally `no execute permission for scripts in /opt/ibc/scripts` .... check permissions of  directory "scripts".

Comment: You only set `+x` for **o**thers - what is the ownership (user and group) of the script(s), and what user is executing `gatewaystart.sh`?

Comment: I have managed to set the permission of /opt/ibc/scripts and successfully ran gatewaystart.sh, however upon restarting my machine the permissions go away. Can anyone help resolve this issue?